# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 in flutter while getting contacts

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I am trying to get contacts from mobile using the [contact services](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service) of flutter i am getting count of all contacts right but it is not showing the contacts on ListView. It giving me the following error.

```
I/flutter (18134): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (18134): The following RangeError was thrown building:
I/flutter (18134): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
I/flutter (18134):
I/flutter (18134): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (18134): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/array.dart:16:52)
I/flutter (18134): #1      ListMixin.elementAt (dart:collection/list.dart:61:33)
I/flutter (18134): #2      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:417:40)
I/flutter (18134): #3      _ContactPageState.contactListView.<anonymous closure> (package:private_call/contact_screen.dart:134:55)
I/flutter (18134): #4      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:446:22)
I/flutter (18134): #5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1134:67)
I/flutter (18134): #6      _HashMap.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/collection_patch.dart:139:29)
I/flutter (18134): #7      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1134:26)
I/flutter (18134): #8      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1147:55)
I/flutter (18134): #9      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2607:19)
I/flutter (18134): #10     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1140:11)
I/flutter (18134): #11     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:354:23)
I/flutter (18134): #12     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1866:58)
I/flutter (18134): #13     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:918:15)
I/flutter (18134): #14     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1866:13)
I/flutter (18134): #15     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:343:5)
I/flutter (18134): #16     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.insertAndLayoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:489:5)
I/flutter (18134): #17     RenderSliverList.performLayout.advance (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:219:19)
I/flutter (18134): #18     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:262:19)
I/flutter (18134): #19     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter (18134): #20     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:135:11)
I/flutter (18134): #21     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:375:11)
I/flutter (18134): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter (18134): #23     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:452:13)
I/flutter (18134): #24     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1783:12)
I/flutter (18134): #25     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1741:20)
I/flutter (18134): #26     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1630:7)
I/flutter (18134): #27     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887:18)
I/flutter (18134): #28     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:402:19)
I/flutter (18134): #29     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:884:13)
I/flutter (18134): #30     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:284:5)
I/flutter (18134): #31     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:15)
I/flutter (18134): #32     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1052:9)
I/flutter (18134): #33     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:968:5)
I/flutter (18134): #37     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:261:10)
I/flutter (18134): #38     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:219:3)
I/flutter (18134): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter (18134): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

[Here is the Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlBMF.png)

I have added isSearching boolean in the Contacts Service Constructor which assign each and every contact a false bool value.

**Here is my Code**

```
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:private_call/appBar.dart';
import 'cards_1.dart';

class ContactPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactPageState createState() => _ContactPageState();
}

class _ContactPageState extends State<ContactPage> {
  Color primaryColorButton = Color(0xFF4C4F5E);
  Icon changeIcon = Icon(Icons.add);
  String private_call = 'Private Call';
  // bool selected = false;
  List<Contact> contacts = [];
  List<Contact> contactsFiltered = [];
  TextEditingController searchController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllContacts();
    searchController.addListener(() {
      filterContacts();
    });
  }

  String flattenPhoneNumber(String phoneStr) {
    return phoneStr.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'^(\+)|\D'), (Match m) {
      return m[0] == "+" ? "+" : "";
    });
  }

  filterContacts() {
    setState(() {
      List<Contact> _contacts = [];
      _contacts.addAll(contacts);
      if (searchController.text.isNotEmpty) {
        _contacts.retainWhere(
          (contact) {
            String searchTerm = searchController.text.toLowerCase();
            String searchTermFlatten = flattenPhoneNumber(searchTerm);
            String contactName = contact.displayName.toLowerCase();
            bool nameMatches = contactName.contains(searchTerm);
            if (nameMatches == true) {
              return true;
            }

            if (searchTermFlatten.isEmpty) {
              return false;
            }

            var phone = contact.phones.firstWhere((phn) {
              String phnFlattened = flattenPhoneNumber(phn.value);
              return phnFlattened.contains(searchTermFlatten);
            }, orElse: () => null);

            return phone != null;
          },
        );

        contactsFiltered = _contacts;
      }
    });
  }

  getAllContacts() async {
    List<Contact> _contacts = (await ContactsService.getContacts()).toList();
    setState(() {
      contacts = _contacts;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isSearching = searchController.text.isNotEmpty;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          AppbarCustom(
            tMain: private_call,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    searchBar(context),
                    contactListView(isSearching),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Expanded contactListView(bool isSearching) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount:
            isSearching == true ? contactsFiltered.length : contacts.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          Contact contact =
              isSearching == true ? contactsFiltered[index] : contacts[index];

          return ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              // print(contact.isSelected);
              // print(contact.phones.elementAt(0).value);
              setState(() {
                (!contacts[index].isSelected)
                    ? contacts[index].isSelected = true
                    : contacts[index].isSelected = false;
              });
              print(index);
              print(contacts[index].isSelected);
            },
            selected: contacts[index].isSelected,
            title: Text(contact.displayName),
            subtitle: CardType(ttText: contact.phones.elementAt(0).value),
            leading: (contact.avatar != null && contact.avatar.length > 0)
                ? CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: MemoryImage(contact.avatar),
                  )
                : CircleAvatar(
                    child: Text(contact.initials()),
                  ),
            trailing: (contacts[index].isSelected)
                ? Icon(Icons.check)
                : Icon(Icons.add),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Container searchBar(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: TextField(
        controller: searchController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Search',
            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: new BorderSide(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
            ),
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.teal.shade300,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When i debug the code i found that error is occurring because of this line

```
subtitle: CardType(ttText: contact.phones.elementAt(0).value)
```

In this method contactListView(bool isSearching)

CardType() is nothing but Text widget

Comment: That's probably because you are not awaiting till you get all the contacts. Try `await getAllContacts()` (of course, you'll have to make another function and call this from there.)

Comment: @Sukhi as per you say i have tried this `waitContact() async {
    await getAllContacts();
  }` it is not working can you please give me the example

Comment: @Sukhi can you please check code again i found the mistake here it is `subtitle: CardType(ttText: contact.phones.elementAt(0).value)` that why it giving me that error when hide this it run perfectly it show the contact name but not number while printing number it give the error. CardType() is nothing but Text widget

Comment: You should add a null check. Perhaps a particular contact does not have any phone number ? `CardType(ttText: contact.phones?contact.phones.elementAt(0).value:'')`

Comment: @Sukhi It work for checking null value it working fine now Thank You.....

Comment: Good to know. I will add it in an answer so that next person having same problem will be benefited as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add null handler checker; as :

```
CardType(ttText: contact.phones?contact.phones.elementAt(0).value:'')
```

Tried running your code but got into some problem. So, I can't tell you what went wrong with 'waitContact()' but you can use FutureBuilder. Something like below should work :

```
return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Enable Notifications"),
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder<bool>(
                future: waitContact(),  
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                        // YOUR CUSTOM CODE GOES HERE
                        return Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                              AppbarCustom(
                                 tMain: private_call,
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                 child: Container(
                                    child: Column(
                                       crossAxisAlignment:     CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                       children: <Widget>[
                                            searchBar(context),
                                            contactListView(isSearching),
                                       ]),
                                  ),
                            ),
                       ],
  );
                    } else {
                        return new CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                }
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
leading: (contact.avatar != null)
                                          ? CircleAvatar(
                                              backgroundImage:
                                                  MemoryImage(contact.avatar),
                                            )
                                          : CircleAvatar(
                                              child: Text(contact.initials()),
                                            ),
```

The argument type 'Uint8List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.